# Change jenkins timestamp according to the browser timezone

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-2

I have a really simple question and couldn't find the answer about. Is it possible to change the jenkins timestamp according to the user's browser timezone. As my Jenkins server is in UTC but some of our users are in Central timezone while other are in few different timezones. So I want that they see the task(s) timestamp according to their browser time/timezone. How we can achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach for this could be to deliver all dates in a default timezone and use momentjs or a similar library to convert the date time on the frontend side to either the browsers timezone (this could be the default) or to a manually selected one.

This would be rather easy to implement and would not require any big changes in jenkins itself, just all places that deliver times must be wrapped in some markup, e.g. a class and some data-fields (e.g. data-datetime containing an rfc3339 timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins issues [JENKINS-19887](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-19887) and [JENKINS-1962](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-1962) detail potential fixes that could be introduced, though they haven't been implemented in any version of the system yet.

If you're only looking for timestamps with the browser's time zone in your console output (with all other timestamps unmodified), [Timestamper](https://plugins.jenkins.io/timestamper) provides this functionality.